# Discrepancy in java Garabage Collection between jconsole and log files

Tags: java, garbage-collecting

I'm having an odd problem:  my garbage collection log file (as defined by -Xloggc) will show n number of garbage collections have taken place, but jconsole will show n+6 garbage collections have taken place.

I'm using the ConcurrentMarkSweep (aka CMS) metric to measure this.  For example, I see 230 examples of "CMS-concurrent-sweep-start" in the log file, but jconsole reports 236 CMS events have taken place.

I'm scratching my head.  Can anyone explain the difference?  Why are there exactly six more CMS events being recorded by jconsole?

Answer (score 0):

Answered this myself not two minutes after posting this.  It's a known bug in java 5, 6 and 6u2.  I was using 6.

The fix is to upgrade java.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6581734